# LinkedIn Share Post V2 API INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: linkedin-api

When trying to share media to a users profile we receive a 500 internal server error with no further explanation.

This is a very basic call based on the V2 doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?context=linkedin/compliance/context#post-shares

{"message":"INTERNAL SERVER ERROR","status":500}

Comment: Need more information, what does your payload contain?

Comment: This usually happens when the payload you're trying to send to LinkedIn is wrong.

Double check the documentation to ensure you're doing everything correctly

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below endpoint to share media to linkedin.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/marketing/context#creating-a-share-on-linkedin

There is three process to post images. Videos upload endpoint not yet released.